# Array of dictionaries in Django models and forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, netbox

I'm working on a static routes plugin for the Netbox project. For my static route object, I need a property, qualified_next_hops, which is a list of dictionary objects. Each item in the list field would have a few keys: next_hop_address, next_hop_interface, admin_distance, route_metric, route_tag.

In my model and forms, what field can I use for this list of dictionaries?

I've used ArrayField elsewhere, but I don't know how to use a dictionary object as the base field. Any advice?

Comment: `JSONField` is the standard, you can use `lists` or `dicts`. What DB are you using? It also helps if you post the code of what you are doing so we can post something useful. Note that it may be smarter in the long run, at least if keys aren't going to change, that you define relational fields for those values. The query will be/can be faster in most instances (in my experience) and for sure any issues that pop up will be easier to debug with defined model attributes